# Random redirects on single URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hi guys is this possible via .htaccess?

```
This URL: example.com/main should randomly redirects to one of these two links: 

1) example-one.com/test1
2) example-two.com/test2
```

I've tried this article but no luck:
[.htaccess redirect to random URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484086/htaccess-redirect-to-random-url)

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using. (There are some fundamental errors in the question/answer you linked to, so it might be a simple fix.) How "random" do you need this to be? The linked question is simply based on "time" so isn't really "random" but might appear so.

Comment: Hello @HELLBORN. Please note that Stack Overflow is here for questions about coding. Your question seems to be related to configuration of a webserver, and for that end you have better to ask at webmasters.stackexchange.com or webapps.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To base the "randomness" on the *seconds* portion of the current time and redirect to URL#1 on *even* seconds and URL#2 on *odd* seconds (when requesting `/main`) then you can do something like the following (before the existing WordPress directives):

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} (0|2|4|6|8)$
RewriteRule ^main$ https://example-one.com/test1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^main$ https://example-two.com/test2 [R,L]
```

Importantly, this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. (A 301 would ordinarily be cached by the browser, so the same user/browser would see the same response on repeated requests - which could be desirable in some scenarios.)

NB: This isn't strictly "random" as it's tied directly to *time*, but might appear random to the casual user.

To implement "real" *random* you would need access to the server config to configure a `rnd` `RewriteMap`, which can then be called from `.htaccess`. But this cannot be configured in `.htaccess` alone.